# How to center a dojo gauge

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I wish to position a gauge in the center of the page. Currently I use "margin-left: 130px;" but then it appears differently on different devices. If I use "margin: 0px auto;" (which works for html table for example) it does not work. Is there some "clever" way to do it?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is dojo specific, but more of a CSS question.
To answer your question; you could try to position the gauge with position:absolute, and set all offsets to 0, like this:

```
position: absolute;
border: 0px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

The html element (a div for example) which contains the gauge should then be positioned relative.

Comment: Could you please elaborate: where in the .css file shall I put your code? How do I position the div with the gauge relative in .html? Thanks!

Comment: That really depends on your HTML. Please post your relevant HTML part.